# History of Morse theory.

Tags: reference-request, math-history, morse-theory

How can I get good references which give many information about history of Morse theory? Now I am interested in how and who found that Hessian have a lot of data. Thank you for your helping!!

Comment: The paper "Morse theory indomitable" can be a starting point: https://eudml.org/doc/104046

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to try these references:

- R. Bott, ["Marston Morse and his mathematical works"](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1980-03-03/S0273-0979-1980-14824-7/), *Bull. Amer. Math. Soc.* 3 (1980) 907–950.
- Dieudonné's *A history of algebraic and differential topology*.
- [Morse theory](http://www.math.harvard.edu/history/bott/bottbio/node9.html) in Tu's *The life and works of Raoul Bott* [[pdf]](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0201027v1.pdf). Also in [Notice of AMS](http://www.tufts.edu/~ltu/doc/23bott06.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest:

1. [Morse Theory Indomitable by R. Bott](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/PMIHES/PMIHES_1988__68_/PMIHES_1988__68__99_0/PMIHES_1988__68__99_0.pdf)  which talks about the development of Morse Theory
2. Morse Theory by J.Milnor which describes the classical approach to Morse Theory and its applications.